# Breaking Type Safety Using Generics

Tags: java, generics, type-safety, type-theory

I have following code when I was able to break type safety.

```java
private static <T extends Number> ArrayList<T> cast2() {
    // This line compiles (1)
    return (ArrayList<T>) new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

private static ArrayList<Double> cast3() {
    // does not compile (3)
    return (ArrayList<Double>) new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    ArrayList<Double> ld1 = cast2();

    // This does not (2)
    ArrayList<Double> ld2 = (ArrayList<Double>) new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

It is obvious that line (2) and (3) are not type safe and does not compile. I'm confused by line(1) which compiles. After substituting Double for T in function cast2 it would be identical that cast3 but cast2 compiles and cast3 does not.

Why is it possible to cast to cast from ArrayList<Integer> to unknown type ArrayList<T> if only type that is sub type of ArrayList<Integer> is ArrayList<Integer> itself?

Comment: It raises a warning.  If you do unchecked casts, you can break type safety; that's what the warning tells you.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I can see the warning but even though compiler raises warning it lets me compile line 1 while it does not let me compile line 2.

Comment: Yes.  Why is that strange?  Line 1 doesn't look inside the implementation of `cast2()`.  Once `cast2()` is compiled, that's it -- the compiler trusts that it does what it says it does.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I explained my reasoning in question body. It seems strange because after doing type substitution these two lines are basicaly identical except for one extra function call.

Comment: You have just spotted it: there is a call in between, with a generic type parameter in the method. I guess the compiler trusts we're not that evil :)

Comment: I agree it's goofy that the compiler allows this.  Might be something to take up on the general OpenJDK mailing list, see if any agrees and wants to tighten the language spec.

Answer (score 2):

> After substituting T for Double in function cast2 it would be identical that cast3 but cast2 compiles and cast3 does not.

Because the way Java generics work isn't to "substitute `T` for `Double`," it's to use erasure.  Generics are only a thing at compile time.  The actual implementation of `cast2()` is

```
return new ArrayList();
```

...with no `<Anything>` at all.  Once `cast2()` is compiled, you can call it with anything, and it won't care.

Comment: So why did it even allow me to cast ArrayList<Integer> to ArrayList<T>. It should know that only subtype of ArrayList<Integer> is ArrayList<Integer> so casting generics does not make sense.

Comment: Because when you do a cast that causes a warning, the compiler is trusting you to know better than it does.  And in this case, it'll _work_ -- casting the `new ArrayList<Integer>()` to an `ArrayList<T>()` will produce an `ArrayList` that works just fine.

Comment: It works only because I did not add anything to list. If I added there some integer then I could cast it to Double which is illegal.

Comment: @Trismegistos: Yes, it works because it was empty when you did the cast and you didn't hold onto a reference to it.  Java doesn't try to work out those details.  If you tell it you're casting to a generic argument, and you ignore the warning that says it's unsafe, then it assumes you know what you're doing.